# How can I transfer voicemail files from an HTC Incredible 2?

Tags: android

My boss wants to purchase a new phone but has an important voicemail message he doesn't want to delete from his current HTC Incredible 2. How can we move/convert that file from his existing device and keep a copy of it on a local hard drive?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this regularly. It could be accomplished by rooting the device. Since you are getting rid of it anyway, it might be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just get a headphone male-male cable and plug it into my computer (mic/input), record into [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) (since it's free) and save the files.  There are more advanced ways, but if the goal is keep them on the drive - then that is probably the simplest.